# Splitting large list into chunks using modulos

Tags: python

I'm wondering why the simple code below doesn't work:

```py
my_list = range(0, 6)

num_proc = 3

chunks = [[]] * num_proc

i = 0
for item in my_list:
    idx = i % num_proc
    i += 1
    chunks[idx].append(item)

print(f"Chunked items = {chunks}")
```

It outputs:

```
Chunked items = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

The output I expect is

```
Chunked items = [[0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5]]
```

Seems that the problem lies with statement

```py
 chunks[idx].append(item)
```

Yet, I'm at a loss on how to fix that

Comment: The reason is explained here: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because when you create your `chunks`list you create 3 sub-list with the same reference.
Therefore when you update it in your code the three sub-lists are updated together.

This line should fix it, it implements chunks in a different way  :

`chunks = [[] for i in range(num_proc)]`

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `[[]] * num_proc` creates a reference of the same list num_proc times so any change to one them updates all of them.

So instead of:

`chunks = [[]] * num_proc`

Do:

`chunks = [[] for _ in range(num_proc)]`